# how to repeat a function with some arguments on some process with pool.starmap

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I used multiprocessing in python for repeating a function 1000 times with one number as input on some cores and I used the code:

```
def GradientProccess(m):
    x=random.seed(os.getpid()*m)
    print(random.seed(os.getpid()*m))
      .
      .
      .
    return()

if __name__ == '__main__':         
    __spec__ = "ModuleSpec(name='builtins', loader=<class '_frozen_importlib.BuiltinImporter'>)"       

    with Pool(processes=8) as pool:

        result=pool.map(GradientProccess,range(1000))
```

But now I am going to use multiprocessing for repeating the function with 2 lists as the input of the function. I want to use `starmap` but how can I repeat it 1000 times? I wrote this code but it is not correct:

```
 def GradientProccess(m,list1,list2):
        x=random.seed(os.getpid()*m)
        print(random.seed(os.getpid()*m))
          .
          .
          .
        return()

    if __name__ == '__main__':         
        __spec__ = "ModuleSpec(name='builtins', loader=<class '_frozen_importlib.BuiltinImporter'>)"       
        list1=[4,3]
        list2=[5,7]
        with Pool(processes=8) as pool:

            result=pool.starmap(GradientProccess,[list1,list2],range(1000))
```

How can I use starmap for repeat a function with 2 fixed lists as arguments?
Is there any other way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the function consumes both lists entirely (and not a combination of elements from each list), you don't need to use `starmap`.  Instead, you can create a [partial function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html?highlight=functools#functools.partial) and use it with `map` as follows.

```
def gradiant_process(m, l1, l2):
    ...

with Pool(processes=8) as pool:
    ...
    import functools
    partial_gp = functools.partial(gradient_process, l1=list1, l2=list2)
    result = pool.map(partial_gp, range(1000))
```